# google app script: i get result null out of nowhere

Tags: function, google-apps-script, logging

i have this code that puzzled  me:

```
Logger.log(jmlTUPDNet)


function TarikDatadanKirim (a,b) {

if (a!=0) {

Logger.log(a)

}}

TarikDatadanKirim(jmlTUPDNet,0)
```

i expected only 2 result but it return 3 result with the third result returned null, like this:
[the third result is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOm2X.png)

i dont know where the null value came from, and it bugged my script ahead. Even, after i erased all other code except code above (no more code after that) the log keeps results 3 logs instead of 2.

where did i miss? help please

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in your showing script, it seems that `jmlTUPDNet` is not declared. From your showing log of `the third result is null`, I think that if `const jmlTUPDNet = 1;` is declared as a global variable, your showing log can be replicated.

I think that when `const jmlTUPDNet = 1;` is declared as a global variable as follows.

```js
const jmlTUPDNet = 1;

Logger.log(jmlTUPDNet)

function TarikDatadanKirim(a, b) {
  if (a != 0) {
    Logger.log(a)
  }
}

TarikDatadanKirim(jmlTUPDNet, 0)
```

In this case, when a function `TarikDatadanKirim` is run, the following flow is run.

1. `const jmlTUPDNet = 1;` is run.
2. `Logger.log(jmlTUPDNet)` is run.

   - By this, `1.0` is shown in the log with `Logger.log(jmlTUPDNet)`.
3. `TarikDatadanKirim(jmlTUPDNet, 0)` is run.

   - By this, `1.0` is shown in the log with `Logger.log(a)`.
4. `function TarikDatadanKirim(a, b) {,,,}` is run.

   - By this, the function `TarikDatadanKirim` is run without arguments. So, `Logger.log(a)` shows `null`.

I guess that this is the reason for your current situation.

If you want to show only `Logger.log(a)`, how about the following modification?

```js
function TarikDatadanKirim(a, b) {
  if (a != 0) {
    Logger.log(a);
  }
}

function sample() {
  const jmlTUPDNet = 1;
  TarikDatadanKirim(jmlTUPDNet, 0);
}
```

By this modification, when you run the function `sample`, `Logger.log(a);` shows `1.0`.