# AppsScript formula error for string type conversion

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to do a simple function in [AppsScript](https://script.google.com/) (is using Javascript) to convert a given date time string which is in a custom date format. I keep getting increasingly weird errors with types. Can someone shed some light on what is going on with the following function.

When I run this I get "Exception: Invalid argument: undefined"
If I pass the dateTimeString directly to the parseDate function, I get error "Exception: Invalid argument: date. Should be of type: String"

```js
/**
 * Converts a string to a date-time value
 *
 * @param dateTimeString
 * @customfunction
 */
function stringToDateTime(dateTimeString) {
  var stringDateTime = new String(dateTimeString)
  var format = Utilities.parseDate(stringDateTime, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
  return format  
}

var x = stringToDateTime("2023-06-30T18:28:01+10:00")
Logger.log(x)
```

Thank you

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, if you directly run the function `stringToDateTime` with the script editor using your showing script, `var x = stringToDateTime("2023-06-30T18:28:01+10:00")` and `Logger.log(x)` are used as the global. By this, the 1st log shows a correct value by them, and the 2nd log shows an error of `Exception: Invalid argument: undefined` occurs by `stringToDateTime(dateTimeString)`. This situation might be related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77885613). If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Cooper I referred the documentation for the parseDate function https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsedatedate,-timezone,-format  it is expecting a string argument. We're trying to parse a string in custom format through this function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [google app script: i get result null out of nowhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77885613/google-app-script-i-get-result-null-out-of-nowhere)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. I think I misunderstood how the script editor works and your answer gave me a hint on what to change. I've added an answer below to help anyone that might encounter such a trivial but annoying issue in future.

Comment: @Babanana thanks, your link has been supportive as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tanaike and Babanana, I've managed to address my issue. The problem had been with my understanding on how the script editor works. I initially thought it would execute the script similar to an interpreter style, but it is not. To fix it all I had to do was extract the testing variable into a new function and execute that function from the editor.

```js
/**
 * Converts a string to a date-time value
 *
 * @param {string} dateTimeString
 * @customfunction
 */
function stringToDateTime(dateTimeString) {
  return Utilities.parseDate(dateTimeString, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
}

function test() {
 const value = stringToDateTime("2023-06-30T18:28:01+10:00");
 Logger.log(value)
}
```

As per code above, I've put in the testing values inside test() function and selected test function to run from editor and it worked fine.