Google App Scripts variable scope not behaving as expected
I'm struggling with Google App Scripts.

My first issue is that the editor insists that I define a function as an entry point, however any inline code outside of that function is also executed after that function.

function myFn() { Logger.log("In Function"); }
Logger.log("In main");
myFn();

produces:
In Function
In main
In Function

While I consider this really REALLY weird, I am working around it by setting a dummy function as the entry point. That may have some bearing on the other stuff I don't understand here.

Variables defined in the inline/main scope do not appear to have global scope.

Attempting to pass an array by reference is not working as I would expect.


Consider:
function byRefFn(myarr) {
   Logger.log("DEBUG: in byRefFn")
   myarr["testing"]="set in byRefFn";
}

function byGlblFn() {
   Logger.log("DEBUG: in byGblFn")
   myarr["testing"]="set in byRefFn";
}

function dummy()
{}

var myarr=[];
byRefFn(myarr);
Logger.log("DEBUG: myarr=" + JSON.stringify(myarr));

byGlblFn();
Logger.log("DEBUG: myarr=" + JSON.stringify(myarr));

Produces....
1:48:59 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:48:59 PM  Info    DEBUG: in byRefFn
1:48:59 PM  Info    DEBUG: myarr=[]
1:48:59 PM  Info    DEBUG: in byGblFn
1:48:59 PM  Info    DEBUG: myarr=[]
1:49:00 PM  Notice  Execution completed

I can just about believe that the inline code is not really executing in global scope, but not being able to set the value for a specific key is a problem. I am aware that using .push(value) the value persists - that does not help.
How should I set a key+value in an array defined in a different scope?
** UPDATE **
If I initialize the variable using myarr = {} rather than myarr = [] I can still assign attributes using myarr[key]=value and JSON.stringify() returns sensible looking data, however I cannot test if the property exists:
 if ('object' == typeof myarr && eventId in myarr) {
    > Cannot use 'in'
    
 if ('object' == typeof myarr && eventId in myarr) {
    > Cannot read properties of null (reading '5aek6fv8na2bgu1dd3ojb6nf5p')
    
 if ('object' == typeof myarr && myarr.hasOwn("eventId")) {
    >  Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasOwn')
    
 if ('object' == typeof myarr && myarr.hasOwnProperty("eventId")) {
    > Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasOwnProperty')


Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, is this thread useful for your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77885613 If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

By the way, about your bottom script and about How should I set a key+value in an array defined in a different scope?, in that case, how about modifying var myarr=[]; to var myarr={};, and also moving byRefFn(myarr); Logger.log("DEBUG: myarr=" + JSON.stringify(myarr)); byGlblFn(); Logger.log("DEBUG: myarr=" + JSON.stringify(myarr)); into function dummy(){}. And run the function dummy again. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

I see very different results from what you posted. See 1 above. Further ECMA defines the behaviour of arrays and objects to be identical when passed as paramters, so I don't see how changing the notation is going to help here. Further the dummy function ONLY exists to satisfy the GAS requirement.

See Clean Code JavaScript.

Why? Can you be more specific?

Apps Script is pure V8 JavaScript, but you may not want to use globals like that because of the way it affects execution. For example, triggers, custom functions and web app doGet() functions all run in different contexts, and there are authorization scopes to consider as well. Use classes or functions to encapsulate your code, and use getters to refer to globals. See How to use global variables while avoiding permission errors?

Replace eventId in myarr with "eventId" in myarr.

Your "update" isn't [mcve].

Related/Duplicate: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63608780/ 2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384141/


var myarr=[];
myarr["testing"]="set in byRefFn";


From JavaScript documentation:

JavaScript arrays are not associative arrays and so, array elements cannot be accessed using arbitrary strings as indexes, but must be accessed using nonnegative integers (or their respective string form) as indexes.

To make it work, declare myarr as an object {} rather than an array [].

Usually things you "cannot" do in a language result in errors when you try to do them. As per update, this solves the JSON.stringify problem, but now I can't test for the existence of the attribute.

Sure you can. The problem with your third example is that myarr is undeclared. Even if it is declared (by code you are not showing), it may be null, and you may find it confusing that, indeed, typeof null === 'object'. See null.

@symcbean To add to this answer,  JSON.stringify doesn't iterate over non-integers, while the array key would still be accessible because all arrays are objects. Therefore, your code will still work if you log it properly: console.log("DEBUG: myarr=" + JSON.stringify(myarr['testing']));  
